# Что означает "Это самое"?

Tags: значения

Как раз услышал "(Ну), это самое". Какое значение?

1. "Это"=it/this. Это понятно.
2. Однако проблема при соединении с "самое", которое само по себе обозначает "именно" (например "Эта самая книга.") или "прямо, как раз".

Отсюда предполагаю, что "это самое значит" что-то вроде "именно это" или "как раз это". Я правильно понимаю? Кто-нибудь меня поправит?

Comment: you definitely should put more effort in asking a question - any additional information can others to give more valuable answers. First, are you asking as a native speaker or not. If you  are asking as a native speaker what exactly you don't understand in this phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как фраза-паразит **это самое** может применяться в двух контекстах. Во втором оно более паразитично, чем в первом.

1. Как попытка напоминания себе и собеседнику о том, о чём только что или недавно шла речь, за которой как правило сразу следует воспроизведение того, что говорящий имел виду. В этом случае оно по сути значит "именно это" или "как раз это".
2. Вне связи с необходимостью напоминания, а просто как заполнитель паузы. В этом случае оно не несёт никакой смысловой нагрузки.

В обоих контекстах оно может применяться и без дополнения "самое", т.е. просто как "это", но в такой форме служит маркером менее развитого и грамотного человека.

**Это самое** может также служить способом привлечения внимания собеседника после некоторой паузы в диалоге, и в этом случае оно синонимично "слушай!", "я говорю".

Comment: Can also be used as a generic placeholder for a verb: "И тогда я это самое и оно теперь вот так, ну ты понял, в общем".

Answer (score 3):

"Это самое" has two meanings - one the literal one (like in "эта самая книга" you've mention) and other meaning makes this phrase to belong to the group of words and phrases that in English are called [`filler words`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics)). In Russian such words called way less neutral - ["слова-паразиты"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B).
Such words bear no meaning and are used to sort of disguise pauses speaker has to deal with.

The literal meaning is way more rare compared the filler meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Выше уже достаточно написали про значение фразы.
От себя могу добавить, что она (эта фраза) может быть употреблена с целью сокрытия предмета разговора, например, в общественном месте по телефону:

Подари ей(подруге) диск с этим самым. - подразумевается, что с эротикой.

Comment: Тогда кажется, что можно было бы расширить первое определение в ответе @Баян Купи-ка  (дополнение пишу заглавными буквами) на "Как попытка напоминания себе и собеседнику о том, о чём только что или недавно шла речь, ИЛИ О ТОМ, ЧТО ПОДРАЗУМЕВАЕТСЯ. Вы согласны?

Answer (score 0):

Я как раз услышал, как используют слово "это самое" ещё в одном значении, и решил собрать вместе все ответы:

1. (@Баян Купи-ка)  Как попытка напоминания себе и собеседнику о том, о чём только что или недавно шла речь, за которой как правило сразу следует воспроизведение того, что говорящий имел виду. В этом случае оно по сути значит "именно это" или "как раз это".
2. (@Баян Купи-ка) Вне связи с необходимостью напоминания, а просто как заполнитель паузы.
3. (@Илья) Употребление с целью сокрытия предмета разговора, например, в общественном месте по телефону:
   Подари ей(подруге) диск с этим самым. - подразумевается, что с эротикой.

[Здесь я бы обобщил ответ @Илья и сказал, что "это самое" можно употребить в случае, когда что-то подразумевается, всем понятно, о чём идёт речь.]

4. Когда человек не может вспомнить название определённого предмета, или например имя человека: "Ты не знаешь, придёт завтра, этот самый..?".
   Однако это значение возможно перекрывается с первым. Хотя может быть на самом деле они и идентичны.

Comment: да, я подразумевал и это в том числе, когда "это самое" остаётся нерасшифрованным, но собсеседнику понятно, о чём речь

Answer (score 0):

`это самое` can also used as an euphemism, for sexual intercourse usually.

Something naughty is being discussed, speaker is not comfortable with this topic so they would employ `это самое`.

I have found an example on second page of search [on ruscorpora](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%FD%F2%EE%20%F1%E0%EC%EE%E5&p=2&docid=114430).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it seems that this is @Илья's answer: "это самое" - что-то, что подразумевается.